# Understanding sil exe in vimscript

Tags: vim

Can someone explain to me what `sil exe ":sb " . current_buffer` does in a vimscript.  I'm trying to learn how to use it, but finding documentation on vimscript seems nearly impossible.

Comment: Documentation is not hard to find, `:h sil`, `:h exe`, `:h :sb` all lead to the right places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a combination of several commands, and all of them are abbreviated.

The commands being used there are `:silent`, `:execute`, and `:sbuffer`. You
can get information on those commands by using `:help :silent` from within vim,
and the same for the other commands.

The `.` operator is also being used to do string concatenation.

First the `.` operator is used to concatenate `:sb` with the value of the
`current_buffer` variable. The resulting string is evaluated as if you'd typed
it by the `:exe` portion, which will supresss messages because it's part of the
`:sil` command.

So, the effect is as if you'd typed `:sb 4`, from normal mode (using 4 there as
the value of `current_buffer`). This would split the current window and use the
new window to edit buffer number 4.